# Mean and Mean Absolute Deviation inferential statistics

Tags: self-study, mean, inference, mad

Consider the following data of runners in a race. The first data is from a certain year the second one is from the year after.

$Last\space year \space|\space Mean: 525s \space|\space MAD: 25s$

$This \space year \space|\space Mean: 613s \space|\space MAD: 21s$

The question asks to make inference from the measures of variability.

My answer:

> The MAD this year is lower than last year, this means that more
> students were closer to the mean time taken to finish the race. Since
> the mean this year is greater than the mean last year, more students
> were slower this year.

I feel like this should be right, but I am not quite sure if it is the right inference from the data given.

Comment: @Tim Isn't MAD = mean absolute deviation

Comment: Both definitions are used, although Median AD is probably more correct. Which definition is used in your problem?

Comment: @user2974951 is most likely Mean AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a [self-study](/questions/tagged/self-study) question so let me just give you some hints to figure it out by yourself.

- [Mean is *sensitive* to outliers.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14210/if-mean-is-so-sensitive-why-use-it-in-the-first-place)
- MAD is an acronym generally used for [median of deviations from median](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247824/why-dont-dispersions-like-median-deviation-and-mode-deviation-exists-on-the-lin). MAD is a [robust measure of variability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33620/outlier-detection-for-heavy-tailed-data), so it is *insensitive* to outliers (see also other questions tagged as [mad](/questions/tagged/mad)). You may want to use it if you have clear outliers in your data.
- The MAD acronym is sometimes is also used for [mean absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation), you'd need to consult your materials for which one is it. If that is the case, if it is defined as an average absolute deviation from the mean, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: It's confusing that it is used as an acronym for both of these things. In my case, MAD was used as an acronym for mean absolute deviation. Thank you, Tim!